# Adding parameters to header does not work while implementing SpringBoot Security JWT for REST API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement authentication and authorization using JWT token in SpringBoot REST API.

In my JWTAuthentication class

```
  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
      FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
        .claim("roles", ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getAuthorities())
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes()).compact();
    res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);    
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
    System.out.println("Token:"+token);
  }
```

When I test my code by sending by posting the following message to 127.0.0.1:8080/login URL, I see that authentication is successful.

```
{"username":"admin", "password":"admin"}
```

And then Spring calls my JWT Authorization class

```
  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    String header = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
      if (header == null) {
        System.out.println("header null");
      } else if (!header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        System.out.println("token prefix missing in header");
      }
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
      return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
```

It prints the message: "token prefix missing in header"

Although I add the TOKEN_PREFIX in the successfulAuthentication method, it can not find it in the header in doFilterInternal method.

By the way, my security config is like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  @Autowired private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        // this disables session creation on Spring Security
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
  }
}
```

I checked the SpringBoot books but could not find a book that describes the inner details of the security framework. Since I did not understand how the framework works, I could not solve the problems by just looking at the blogs. Is there a book that you can suggest describing the details of SpringBoot Security?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You set your token after you successfully authenticated the user to the header of 
the Http *response*:

```
res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
```

The internal JWT filter (from what I understand in your question is called after yours), looks in the Http headers of the *request*

```
String header = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
```

and there they are not present.

In general, the second filter should not be active after you authenticated a user and should just return the JWT token to the client. Any subsequent call of the client should then include the JWT token in the `Authorization` header using `Bearer: YourJWTToken` for calling e.g. protected APIs.